# Newton polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

Consider the family of symmetric polynomials $\sum^n_{i=1} x_i^k\in\mathbf{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. By the fundamental theorem on symmetric polynomials there is a unique *Newton poylnomial* $N_k\in\mathbf{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ such that $\sum^n_{i=1} x_i^k=N_k(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$ with $s_i$ the elementary symmetric polynomials. Is there a way to compute the polynomials $N_k$ by means of e.g. a recursion formula? 
Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities)?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember there is this :

http://www.imm.dtu.dk/arith21/presentations/pres_92.pdf

I assume thay you will want to evalute them at points.

(Newton's identites are theoretically good, but practically intractable when the number of variables becomes big.)